# add a pass without instance of PKAddPassesViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, passbook

In doc

> To add a pass to the library:
>
> - Create an instance of the PKPass class for the pass, initializing it with the pass’s data.
> - Use the containsPass: method of the PKPassLibrary class to check whether the pass is in the library. Your app can use this method to detect the presence of a pass, even if it doesn’t have the entitlements to read passes in the library.
> - If the pass isn’t in the library, use an instance of the PKAddPassesViewController class to let the user add it.
>   Present the add passes view controller modally, with animation.

Is there any way to add a pass to my passbook without initializing PKAddPassesViewController?

Answer (score 1):

[Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPass_Ref/PKPass.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/PKPass) clearly says, The `PKPass` class represents a single pass.
Also, there is no such method in `PKClass` to add it in the library.

So, you need to use `PKAddPassesViewController` that lets your app show a pass and prompt the user to **add** that pass to the pass library.

Comment: we have a method like "PKAddPassesViewController(passes: pkPasses) as PKAddPassesViewController" to add multiple pass where pkPasses is an array of pkpass